# how to get a value ajax from form that have array value

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

i have form input that value is will be an array from that array i will get a value to ajax and javascript code to get other value for next form,
please evaluate my code, because it not running and doesn't show any error

```
<table>
  <form>
<?php
 for($i=1;$i<=$jml;$i++){?>
   <tr>
   <td>Jenis CI</td>
   <td><select class="form-control" name="jenis2[]"id="jenis2[]" required>
       <?php foreach($relasi as $row) { ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row->idJenisCI;?>"><?php echo $row->namaJenisCI;?> 
       </option><?php } ?>
       </select>
   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Nama CI</td>
   <td><select  class="id2 form-control" name="id2[]" required></select></td>
   </tr>
<?php }?>
   <tr align="center">
   <td colspan="2"><input class="tombol" type="submit" name="submit" value="Simpan"></td>
   </tr>

 </form>
</table>
```

and this my javascript and ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#jenis2').change(function(){
            var idJenisCI=$(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/C_ProyekAkhir/option",
                method : "POST",
                data : {idJenisCI: idJenisCI},
                async : false,
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        html += '<option value="'+data[i].idCI+'-'+data[i].namaCI+'">'+data[i].namaCI+'</option>';
                    }
                    $('.id2').html(html);

                }
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: what is your expected output in the controller? can you do print_r($_POST) in C_ProyekAkhir/option?

Comment: no its not in the controller, but that t in the view ,

Comment: the result of the javascript and ajax will be return to the form and will be value for other select form

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#jenis2').change(function(){
            var idJenisCI=$(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/C_ProyekAkhir/option",
                method : "POST",
                data : {idJenisCI: idJenisCI},
                async : false,
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    var decode_response = JSON.parse(data); // Add This New Line
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        html += '<option value="'+data[i].idCI+'-'+data[i].namaCI+'">'+data[i].namaCI+'</option>';
                    }
                    $('.id2').html(html);

                }
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: what for that line?

Comment: and that not running

Comment: the second select option still empty